# Javascript es6 + Webpack referencing imports

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs, es6-class

I am trying to work out why i can reference an import from one file, but not the other 
(I think it is to do with the way javascript works and that I cannot reference a variable before it is defined... If that is the case then i'm hoping one of you can give me some reference to a workaround for that.)
I am building an electron app with webpack and babel.

my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 entry: {
  app: ['./app/src/app.js', './app/src/test.js']
 },
 output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: './app/lib/bundle.js'
 },

 module: {
  loaders: [
   {
    test: /.js?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
     presets: ['env']
    }
   }
  ]
 },
};
```

And my app.js

```
import { test, foo } from './app';

class app {
 constructor() {
  console.log("hello from app.js");
 }
}

// let a = new test(); // gives error (shown below)
// foo(); // same exact error but referencing function instead of constructor

export { app };
```

And test.js

```
import { app } from './app';

class test {
 constructor() {
  console.log("hello from test.js");
 }
}

let foo = () => console.log("foo");

let b = new test(); // works as expected

export { test, foo };
```

the error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _app.test is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:88)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:63)
    at bundle.js:66
```

So I can call classes from app inside test, but cannot do the same the other way around? why?

Thanks for responses in advance

Comment: Wait what? Why are you importing something from itself? Why are you trying to import test and foo from app *inside app*??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a circular dependency issue. Your `app` imports `test`, which in turn imports `app`.

Comment: I think they made a typo in `import { test, foo } from './app'`, meaning to import it from `'./test'`. If so, then they would probably get a stack overflow from the circular dependency I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you commenters Luke and Li357.
I was breaking my brain over this and confused myself with folder names vs file names.

The problem was i was importing files from the same places and causing circular dependency error.

Solved.